# How to integrate wicket framework with mongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, wicket

I have using spring-data-mongodb 1.2.1-RELEASE in quick start application. it is working fine, 
i can connect to mongo db i can create,update and delete collection now i want to integrate wicket-framework with this application.

Domain class

```
@Document
public class Student
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Student repository class

```
@Repository
public class StudentService 
{

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void create(Student student)
    {
        mongoTemplate.insert(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Query query, Update update)
    {
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Student.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAll()
    {
        List<Student> students = mongoTemplate.findAll(Student.class);
        logger.debug("Student: {}", students);
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Student student)
    {
        mongoTemplate.remove(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll()
    {
        Query searchUserQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("age").gt(0));
        mongoTemplate.remove(searchUserQuery, Student.class);
    }
}
```

Mongo configuration class

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MongoDBApp.class})
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
    {
        @Override
        protected String getDatabaseName()
        {
            return "demo";
        }  

        @Override
        public Mongo mongo() throws Exception
        {
           return new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        }

        @Override
        protected String getMappingBasePackage()
        {
            return "mypackage";
        }
   }
```

Mongo Db main class

```
public class MongoDBApp
{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDBApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.info("Demo application");

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfiguration.class);

        StudentService studentService = context.getBean(StudentService.class);

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("foo");
        student.setAge(24);
        studentService.create(student);

        List<Student> students = studentService.findAll();
        logger.info("No. of students: {}", students.size());


        studentService.delete(student);
        logger.info("Deleted student: {}", student);
   }
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For this code i want to integrate with wicket framework.

Please help me how to do that?

Comment: Be more specific and show some code please...

Comment: Martijn Dashorst, Thank you very much for your reply. I am updated my question.

Comment: I still don't know what you want to achieve. What is it that you want Wicket to do? Build you a car, plane, swimming pool?

Comment: I want to do CRUD operation in StudentPage what i have done in main class. For this, can i invoke student service from student page like @Repository StudentService service;?. And what are the dependency i want to add in my pom.xml file.

Comment: I am extremely sorry to ask this foolish question. Just i created page for student.And invoke service like  ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    StudentService studentService = context.getBean(StudentService.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your Spring/MongoDb works well you just need to integrate it into Wicket with module wicket-spring. You can find and example of this integration here:

http://wicketguide.comsysto.com/guide/chapter18.html#chapter18_2

The source is available here:

https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples/tree/master/SpringInjectionExample

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrea del bence,
I did like this in MyWicketApplication

```
@Override
public void init()
{
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, getSpringContext()));
        // add your configuration here
}

public ApplicationContext getSpringContext()
{
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
}
```